# 3g modem that works out of the box with Linux

Tags: usb, router

I want a 3g Modem.

I want it to work without running the propreitary `install.sh` provided on the modem as a U3 disk.

I want it to work with open drivers.

I bought [D-Link DWM-157](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426540/3g-d-link-dwm-157-modem-install-on-ubuntu-12-04) but it seems to need propreitary drivers and the Windows certificate for the exceutble is revoked cos of a leak of certificates.

The companies that are easily available where I live are ZTE, HUAWEI, TP-LInk, D-Link.

Go to http://amazon.in and http://ebay.in for checking if the particualr model is available.